# Setting a class in a inner element of a component instead of on the selector itself

Tags: css, angular, angular6

I would like to add a class into a component in a angular component (v6) using the HostBinding. So far I have the following piece of code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-boat',
  templateUrl: './boat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./boat.component.scss']
})

export class BoatComponent {
    @HostBinding('class.dragging') dragging = false;

    @HostListener('pointerdown', ['$event'])
    onPointerdown(event: PointerEvent): void {
        this.dragging = true;
    }   
}
```

boat.component.html

```
<div class="boat" >
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="boatpieces"></ng-container>  
</div>
```

With that example, it will add a class to the app-boat component itself the following way:

```
<app-boat class="dragging"></app-boat>
```

but my goal is to inject the "dragging" class to the `<div class="boat dragging" >`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `[ngClass]` or `[class.draggable]` in your Boat Component Template:

```
<div class="boat" [class.dragging]="dragging">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="boatpieces"></ng-container>  
</div>
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-draggable-class-eg?file=src/app/boat/boat.component.html) for your ref.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is with input binding. You can define a `boatClass` input property in the child component:

```
export class BoatComponent {

  @Input() boatClass: string;

  ...
}
```

and apply it to the `div` element in the template with `[ngClass]`:

```
<div class="boat" [ngClass]="boatClass">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="boatpieces"></ng-container>  
</div>
```

In the parent component, you set the class to the appropriate value:

```
<app-boat boatClass="dragging"></app-boat>
<app-boat [boatClass]="'dragging'"></app-boat>
<app-boat [boatClass]="getBoatClass()"></app-boat>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oijdjz) for a demo.